# Matlab NQueens Algorithm Recursion

Tags: matlab, recursion, n-queens

For an assignment I was tasked to devise an NQueens algorithm using Matlab and recursion. So the way I've set it up is I have 2 helper functions isValid, which tests for valid placement, and recursiveQueen, which places or removes a queen from a MxM board of 0's and adds one or removes 1 from every possible move the queen can make. For sake of space I removed the add functions from the recursiveQueen function, but all it does is add or subtract 1 in 8 directions.

The main problem I am having is in my solveNQ function getting it to go to the next column if no solutions are found for the preceding row. I've broken my steps down to 6 things:

1)Place a queen in the first row

2)Place a queen in the next row next valid position

3)Repeat step 2 until no valid placement is found for row

4)Remove the queen from the last row

5)Place the queen in the next valid spot of the row

6)Repeat step 1-5 until all rows contain a queen (I haven't coded this step in)

```
function out = NQueens(m) %main function
board = zeros(m,m); %intializes board
out = solveNQ(1,board) %recursive function
end

function out = solveNQ(col,board)
n = length(board);
out = false; %returns false if no solutions found
if col > n  
else
    for i = col:n 
        for j = 1:n
            if isValid(board,i,j)
                board = recursiveQueen(board,i,j,'place') %place queen
                out = solveNQ(col+1,board) %recursive call
            end
        end
        board = recursiveQueen(board,i-1,col,'remove') %if no valid placement for row
        out = solveNQ(col-1,board) %try again
    end
end
end


function out = isValid(board,row,col)
    if board(row,col) == 0
       out = true;
    else
       out = false;
end

function board = recursiveQueen(board,row,col,move)
board = goRight(board,row,col,move); %right
board = goLeft(board,row,col,move); %left
board = goDown(board,row,col,move); %down
board = goUp(board,row,col,move); %up
board = goRightUp(board,row,col,move); %diagnol up right
board = goLeftUp(board,row,col,move); %diagnol up left
board = goRightDown(board,row,col,move); %diagnol right down
board = goLeftDown(board,row,col,move); %diagnol left down
    if strcmp(move,'place') %places queen
        board(row,col) = -1; 
    elseif strcmp(move,'remove') %removes queen
        board(row,col) = 0;
     end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't need the second loop for j= because your col+1 would allow you to move onto the next column.

The concept I have is as follows

1) Place a queen at the top left corner

2) Move to the next column and place a queen where it is valid

3) Repeat step 2, so now we are at column 3. If you can't put any queen there, then remove the previous queen. The main problem with your current code can be solved by moving the queen remove inside the if statement. The logic behind this is that when no queens can be placed in that column, the for loop will run without actually doing anything (since isValid is false). When the for loop (this is the for loop INSIDE the recursion) stops running, MATLAB will pick up where it left off previously, which is your clone solveNQ, and jump to the next line, where you should remove your queen.

Don't forget that if n>col, which means you are able to place N Queens onto the board, your output is true.

I had to have a friend help me with this problem as well. Feel free to reply if my explanation was bad.